# $10$ object in $2$ equal queues

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm working on the following.

Ten objects shall be arranged in two queues of equal length. The order matters.

a) A and B must be in different queues.

b) A and B must be next to each other in the same queue.

Objects = $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J$

Queues = $1,2$

a)
If we first place A, then there are 10 possible positions. If we then place B, then there are 5 possible positions. Then we will place the other eight objects in 8 possible positions. Then the same thing, but B is placed first, then A.

$$10\cdot 5 \cdot \binom{8}{8} \cdot 2=4032000$$

But if we place all then objects without restraints, we get a lower number. What am I doing wrong?

$$\binom{10}{10}=3628800$$

b) Calculate if A and B are next to each other in 1. Then the same thing for 2.

$$2\cdot \binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{8}{8}=1612800$$

EDIT:

a) Removed the double counting. $$10\cdot 5 \cdot \binom{8}{8} =2016000$$

b) A and B can be placed next to eachother in each queue $2\cdot4$ possible ways (order matters). Then we've 2 queues, $2\cdot8$.

$$16\cdot \binom{8}{8} =645120$$

Comment: It seems that you use $\binom{n}{k}$ in a strange way. It seems thta you use it for the number of ways to select $k$ objects from $n$ objects and place them at $k$ different position. This number would be $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. But usually $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to select a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ objects. And this number is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. The answers use  $\binom{n}{k}$ in the usual meaning, too.

Comment: To be fair, I have seen the $\binom{n}{k}$ notation represent the permutation function before in texts. It’s just less common, and should probably be clarified or avoided altogether by just writing out the factorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part a, I think you're double-counting when you consider if $A$ is placed first or if $B$ is placed first. If you like thinking in terms of cases then it may be more helpful to first think of all the cases where $A$ is in queue $1$ and double that to count all of the cases where $A$ is in queue $2$. Here it's clear that any ordering which is in one set can't be in the other, and all of the orderings must be in one set or the other. So I think the answer you want is $2016000$.

Then for part b I think the factor of $5 \choose 2$ is wrong, I think that would be correct if they only had to be in the same queue, but here they also have to be next to each other. I would count that by first looking at the number of ways two elements can be placed next to each other in a queue of $5$ (there are $4$) and then doubling that to account for the ordering, getting $8$ total. So I get $645120$ possible orderings.

Answer (score 1):

For the part a) the answer is
$$2\binom84 (5!)^2=50\cdot 8!,
$$
where the first factor stays for the number of queues to place A, the second factor for the choice of the other objects joining A in the queue, and the third factor for the number of ways to permute both queues.

For the part b) the answer is
$$2\binom83 (4\cdot2!)3!5!=16\cdot8!,
$$
where the first factor stays for the number of queues to place A and B, the second factor for the choice of the other 3 objects joining A and B in the queue, the third factor for the number of ways to arrange A and B in the queue, the forth and fifth factors for the number of ways to permute the other objects in the two queues.